# Working with complex formula in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, excel

Just wanted to get your inputs on what would be the best way to work with complex formula in SharePoint, while allowing users to easily make edits in the formula (if needed). My understanding is that formula in SharePoint is not very user friendly, especially complex formula, and some might even require certain coding experience. That being said, I'm wondering what are the options out there regarding excel and SharePoint integration.

One option I thought of is to convert excel templates with multiple tabs and complex formula into SharePoint but the downside is that users won't be able to see the formula since the imported data would be displayed in SP list as hardcoded number. Any thoughts/ideas/feedback would be much appreciated. Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Formula simplification in this area may be difficult to improve in SharePoint.

Not all excel formulas can be used in SharePoint, the formulas in SharePoint have their own logical structure.

In fact, complex formulas are difficult to simply modify in excel or sharepoint.

All we can do is to create formulas using simple logic as much as possible.

This [MSDN article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) lists various functions that can be used in SharePoint calculated columns

Comment: Thank you. Btw do you know if we import an Excel file to SharePoint List, if you make the changes to the Excel and save it, will that changes be saved in the SharePoint List?

Comment: If you open directly from the local, it will not automatically update in SharePoint.

Comment: So I have multiple excel files (can be local or online) with the same format. My end goal is to have one SharePoint consolidated lists that have all the data from each of those Excel file table. So when I add a excel file --> the new excel table will be added to SharePoint List. When I update a value in the existing excel file, it will update in SharePoint list as well. The question is, is it possible? I know I can build workflow for converting excel data to SP List individually but not sure how to handle multiple files.